# sed not working as expected (trying to get value between two matches in a string)

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file (/tmp/test) the has a the string "aaabbbccc" in it

I want to extract "bbb" from the string with sed.

Doing this returns the entire string:

```
sed -n '/aaa/,/ccc/p' /tmp/test
```

I just want to return bbb from the string with sed (I am trying to learn sed so not interested in other solutions for this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/aaa\(.*\)ccc/\1/' /tmp/test
```

Output:

```
bbb
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 3):

Sed works on a line basic, and `a,b{action}` will run action for lines matching `a` until lines matching `b`. In your case

```
sed -n '/aaa/,/ccc/p'
```

will start printing lines when `/aaa/` is matched, and stop when `/ccc/` is matched which is not what you want.

To manipulate a line there is multiply options, one is `s/search/replace/` which can be utilized to remove the leading `aaa` and trailing `ccc`:

```
% sed 's/^aaa\|ccc$//g' /tmp/test
bbb
```

Breakdown:

```
s/
  ^aaa  # Match literal aaa in beginning of string
  \|    # ... or ...
  ccc$  # Match literal ccc at the end of the sting
//      # Replace with nothing
g       # Global (Do until there is no more matches, normally when a match is
        # found and replacement is made this command stops replacing)
```

If you are not sure how many `a`'s and `c`'s you have you can use:

```
% sed 's/^aa*\|cc*$//g' /tmp/test
bbb
```

Which will match literal `a` followed by zero or more `a`'s at the beginning of the line. Same for the `c`'s but just at the end.